# WPF Focus Animation not working properly

Tags: wpf, animation, user-controls

I have a WPF usercontrol set up in XAML with the following Triggers:

```
   <UserControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="GotFocus">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation To="1.5" Storyboard.TargetName="ImageContent" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[1].ScaleX" Duration="0:0:0.8" />
                    <DoubleAnimation To="1.5" Storyboard.TargetName="ImageContent" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[1].ScaleY" Duration="0:0:0.8" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="LostFocus">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation To="1" Storyboard.TargetName="ImageContent" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[1].ScaleX" Duration="0:0:0.8" />
                    <DoubleAnimation To="1" Storyboard.TargetName="ImageContent" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[1].ScaleY" Duration="0:0:0.8" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </UserControl.Triggers>
```

The Animation is working fine but unfortunately the Triggers arent working as expected. The GotFocus trigger only fires if i Right-Click my Control or if i Click a Button that is contained within the UserControl.

I have created an EventHandler for the GotFocus event in code and that seems to fire in the right places.

Edit: If I change it to Fire on MouseEnter / Leave it also works as expected

Edit2: I foudn out that this behaviour is surfacing because the Control gets focus, but loses the focus again right away. I fixed it by adding some code, that checks if the source of the Event is the UserControl or something else.

Any hints on why this is happening would be appreciated.

Comment: I am a little confused by your Edit2. Are you saying you found the reason and fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

Try settings Focusable="True" on the UserControl.